# Can I ask a question about video game based scifi/fantasy?

Tags: discussion, faq, scope

As an occasional consumer of Halo books/games, I'm often curious about certain plot points or want to ask questions about that game's universe. Would this be the appropriate site for these questions? Or is gaming.stackexchange.com the appropriate site? Or is this an area of overlap where both would be equally appropriate?

Note that a lot of these games, such as Halo, have a decently sized expanded universe in the form of books/comics/movies that would seem to invite questions on this site. Does the existence of an expanded universe have any implications for this question? Note too that scifi.stackexchange.com doesn't seem to differentiate between scifi from books/movies/television. Why would games be any different?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Which mediums can be the basis of questions?](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/400/which-mediums-can-be-the-basis-of-questions)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

I think you can ask questions about the **plot** and even production of the game. And you can certainly ask about the "expanded universe" you mention (books, comics & movies).

Off topic would be **gameplay**, e.g. "how do I complete task X?" Please take that to [Arqade](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/).