# Whats the particular description of the genre's Science Fiction and Fantasy, as it pertains to this site?

Tags: discussion, questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which mediums can be the basis of questions?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/400/which-mediums-can-be-the-basis-of-questions)

Pretty obvious question, seeking the understanding for all of us. Does this site encompass all Science Fiction and Fantasy work including Games, Art, Short Stories etc...? What kind of Science Fiction is not permitted? Is their no outer limits to what can be posted here?

Yes I do think I'm clever, even when the other side of me knows I'm not.

The other thing I should ask is, fantasy can sometimes be a bread of historical fiction as well. Dow we include those kinds of fantasy works? My questions would like a nice answer, Smile.

Thank You!

Comment: And see also [What is and what isn't considered science fiction?](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/q/37), [Would non-horror Speculative Fiction be on-topic for this site?](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/q/537), and other [topic discussion questions](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faq+on-topic-discussion).

Comment: I get the point, Gilles... Sorry for the extra duplicate. I'd suggest adding one of these to f&q.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that all Sci-Fi content is on-topic whether in "Games, Art, Short Stories etc".  But you have to stick to the Sci-Fi elements of that media.

For example, one could ask question about the origins of the Collectors in [Mass Effect 2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass_Effect_2), but one can't ask on this site how to find all the hidden power-ups.

As to Fantasy/Historical Fantasy, in my mind as long as the story has some fantastical elements then it is on-topic.  If it's merely a non-fantastical dramatization about a historical event without an alternate outcome, then it is off-topic.

So I think something like [Eaters of the Dead](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eaters_of_the_Dead), is technically on-topic even though most of the supernatural events in the story could have a mundane origin.

*this is how I see things, others are free to disagree, of course.