# Comic Books and other Graphic novels

Tags: discussion, comics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which mediums can be the basis of questions?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/400/which-mediums-can-be-the-basis-of-questions)

If I had questions about say X-men or a certain story arc win X-Men Vol 2 or whatever, would that type of question be kosher here (or any other type of question dealing with comics in general)? Or is this site more for sci-fi/fantasy novels/movies?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's welcome here.  In fact there are already a few comic book questions with excellent answers.

Comment: Ok cool. Didn't want to be shunned away if I have a question about a story line or something lol. Thanks.