# Can we get comic books officially added to the site's scope?

Tags: discussion, comics

Given that we have many comic book questions, and several meta questions discussing that comic books are on topic, can we add it to the site's scope officially?  What's the process to do that?

Comment: What constitutes officially? I ask because I don't think we list any media types as 'supported' anywhere.

Comment: @DampeS8N I'm not sure, which is why I ask.  If the FAQ's the source of truth, then I've done as Gilles requested below, so my request is filled I think.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's nothing in the [site FAQ](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/faq) about media, so by default I'd say there's no restriction of which media are within the scope of the site.

If you're still in doubt, turn to the `faq` tag on Meta, in which you'll find
[Which mediums can be the basis of questions?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/400/which-mediums-can-be-the-basis-of-questions), where the consensus is that all media are on-topic.

It's true that the site FAQ could use an overhaul. You can help by proposing improvements [in the old, but still open meta question on the topic](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/549/what-should-our-faq-contain).