# Would "Skullgirls" be considered Sci-Fi/Fantasy enough for this SE?

Tags: discussion, scope

I have a question about the mechanics of the Skull Heart from the video game Skullgirls - not an in-game mechanics question, but speicfically a lore question.

Skullgirls, for those who don't know, is a fighter game involving:

- An ancient artifact/being known as the "Skull Heart" that grants a single wish to the girl who finds it, but will transform them into the Skullgirl and destroy them if their heart is impure.
- A plethora of monstrous characters, including parasitic hair, a zombie catgirl, a demonically posessed hat, and many more.
- Numerous biologically engineered characters designed as living weapons and parodies of various cartoon characters.
- Very large...eyes.

With all of that in consideration, would it be acceptable to ask a question about this game on this site?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> An ancient artifact/being known as the "Skull Heart" that grants a single wish to the girl who finds it, but will transform them into the Skullgirl and destroy them if their heart is impure.

Sounds on-topic.

> A plethora of monstrous characters, including parasitic hair, a zombie catgirl, a demonically posessed hat, and many more.

Sounds on-topic.

> Numerous biologically engineered characters designed as living weapons and parodies of various cartoon characters.

Sounds on-topic.

> Very large...eyes.

Sounds fun, but not inherently on-topic.

---

Provided that the question had to do with the lore and not the... *eyes*, you should be OK.

Comment: If it was just a video game about a bunch of people with unfeasibly large eyes, it would probably still be on topic...

Comment: Of course you know what 'large eyes' refers to...the fact that it's all done in a very anime-esque style, of course!

Answer (score 7):

It seems that no-one has linked back to previous discussion, so I'll just put this here - a four year old question here in meta, massively upvoted (26 upvoted, 0 downvotes as of this moment) agreeing that lore/background/story questions about video games are on-topic here on the site. Strange that it doesn't show up on the Related Questions sidebar.

[Can I ask a question about video game based scifi/fantasy?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/319/can-i-ask-a-question-about-video-game-based-scifi-fantasy/320)

Does anyone want to reopen the issue, or is the previous consensus acceptable?

Comment: I don't think anyone disagrees that it's on topic here, just whether or not it's a "better fit" elsewhere.

Answer (score -3):

I'm going to disagree here and say that the question doesn't belong here. Yes, its "on-topic" in the sense that it deals with a fantasy world, but belongs elsewhere

If you post here and not at Arqade you will get worse answers and it will be hard to find for other gamers looking for skullgirls content.

If you post here and at Arqade you will get better answers at Arqade anyway, so why post here?

In the end there isn't any advantage to posting here, because people looking for information on skullgirls will be looking on Arqade, not here.
Arqade does welcome Lore questions, so that isn't an issue. Just post it there.

What we don't want is video game lore questions being on a separate site from mechanics questions, it just doesn't make sense.

Comment: I agree in general...but what about the number of Mass Effect and other video game questions that *are* on this site?  Are they misclassified?  Or do some of them belong here despite being of video game origin?

Comment: @zibbobz Well mass effect is multimedia, there are several novels and I think an animation as well. So it doesn't belong exclusively on Arqade. As far as I am aware the game is the only part of the Skullgirls universe

Comment: An example of a question that definitely does not relate to other media: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/33194/what-does-qbert-say-when-he-dies And there are plenty of others that, while the franchise itself extends beyond video games, ask about the video game directly.

Comment: @Zibbobz I would say that some questions belong elsewhere, including that one.

Comment: In my experience (not a ton, I mostly just poke around over there once in a while), I find that Arqade doesn't do as well with story-based questions when it comes to games. While the stories are definitely on topic there, they seem to primarily focus on game mechanics. While it may be a better fit, or find a better audience on one or the other, it's on topic on both sites and doesn't "belong" on either site any more than the other.