# Are questions about the backstory of a sci fi or fantasy Lego set on topic here?

Tags: discussion, scope

Lego frequently comes out with various themed sets with science fiction or fantasy themes, often with a back story.  An example would be the [Mars Mission sets](http://lego.wikia.com/wiki/Mars_Mission).

As per the Brickipedia page:

> The theme focuses on the adventures of a team of Astronauts as they
>   land on Mars and are forced to contend with a dangerous alien race.

I was wondering whether these would be considered to be on-topic for this site.  Note I'm specifically asking about the **story** behind these series of Lego sets, *not* about the Lego sets themselves.

Comment: http://bricks.stackexchange.com/ - Specialists in all things lego...

Comment: We have some questions about [bionicle](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/search?q=bionicle) already. Granted, I think there was a tv show and a game or two, but I don't see much of a difference.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As a guy with a *major* ScienceFictionLegoAddiction, I think it would benefit Bricks SE if we go there when we have Lego questions to ask. They need the traffic and the topic is spot on in Bricks SE whereas the topic is sort of peripheral to SciFi&F.

Comment: I don't disagree with this sentiment.

Comment: I think this is probably a fair call as well +1

Answer (score 4):

In principle yes. The backstory of a SciFi- or Fantasy-themed toy or game would be well within topic.

- [Can I ask a question about video game based scifi/fantasy?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/319/can-i-ask-a-question-about-video-game-based-scifi-fantasy)
- [Does a stuffed 'Toby the Targ' toy exist?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/48697/does-a-stuffed-toby-the-targ-toy-exist)

That being said, I'd be quite surprised if there's more of a backstory to these sets beyond the miniature story cards and storybooks that were found in some 1980s sets. Nowadays they don't even seem to have those.

Comment: What about the Lego Yoda Chronicles?  There's quite a big backstory there!

Comment: @N_Soong - That would be very much pn-topic. Given the large number of people involved in the voice, production and animation I'd expect there to be a wealth of interviews and additional info available.

Comment: While technically on-topic, the problem with Lego Yoda Chronicles is that like Spaceballs, it's *meant* to be a non-canon parody, so many questions won't have answers. Not grounds for closing, of course, but it makes a lot of questions kind of pointless.

Comment: @phantom42 - Well, it's non-canon **to the main universe**. That doesn't mean that there's no reason why stuff happens, it's just not necessarily for any greater reason than "because it's funny".

Comment: The backstories aren't usually included inside the sets or on the boxes these days, because that sort of content is included on the product's web pages. If there is further backstory to current/recent sets, you'll find it on LEGO.com.

Comment: @CreationEdge - That's pretty lame. I remember in the good old days when [computer games](http://www.c64sets.com/set.html?id=88), lego sets, etc came with their own little comic books to give you insight.

Comment: Sometimes you get comics, in certain sets, or in the kid's LEGO Club Magazines (which I just realized are another source of story). However, LEGO takes strides to be more Green, including reducing the empty space in boxes, reducing box size, and use certified sustainable material. [See here](http://www.lego.com/en-us/aboutus/news-room/2013/february/smaller-lego-boxes-easier-on-the-environment). Including more paper than necessary inside the kits would kind of go against that initiative!