# Joint SFF/Arqade Topic Challenge: The Elder Scrolls (August 2021)

Tags: discussion, topic-challenge

This post is for the eighth of SFF.SE's new series of **topic challenges**, encouraging the site's community to take part together in asking and answering questions on a particular topic each month. According to community votes on the [topic challenge proposals thread](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13240/31394), the August 2021 topic challenge is going to be devoted to a [series of action role-playing video games](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Elder_Scrolls):

### *The Elder Scrolls*

### [the-elder-scrolls](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-elder-scrolls)

Since this series is on-topic both here on SFF and on our [sister site devoted to gaming, Arqade SE](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-elder-scrolls-*), the two sites' mod teams [have agreed](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15955/arqade-scifi-cross-site-topic-challenge-the-elder-scrolls) to make this event a **joint cross-site topic challenge**. This is an exciting new experiment in collaboration between different sites in the SE network.

---

**What's a topic challenge and how/where do I take part?**

See [Announcing a Topic Challenge program for SFF.SE](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13211/31394), and also [this main meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/240634/278659). In short, during August 2021 we should all try to either ask interesting questions about *The Elder Scrolls*, or help out by answering other people's questions about it. For this particular topic challenge, you can ask either on SFF or on Arqade, so let's recall [our policy](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/319/31394) about what to ask where:

- **Lore** and **plot** questions, related to the fictional setting or storyline of the game, are on-topic here on SFF.
- **Gameplay** questions, about technical aspects or how the playing works, are better suited for Arqade.

Participation is not obligatory in any sense, but those who participate will be forever remembered in the [annals of our history](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13441/31394). We'll keep a list of all *Elder Scrolls* questions asked during August 2021 in an answer to this meta post. At the end of the month, I'll collate some data like highest-scoring question, most-viewed question, highest-scoring answer, etc. There won't be any real-world rewards like in [the old days](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1138/31394) when Stack Exchange was smaller and more generous, but I'll be awarding at least one bounty after the end of the month (assuming there's at least one good answer posted on the SFF side of the challenge).

---

**What's next?**

Future SFF topic challenges will be chosen by community votes, so come over and propose or vote on suggestions at:

[Propose future topics for SFF topic challenges!](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13240/31394)

(The *Elder Scrolls* answer will be deleted from that thread at the start of August, since already chosen topics shouldn't stick at the top of the thread and distract people from those still to be voted on.)

Comment: Nice! TES lore is even worse for me than TVTropes time-suck wise.

Comment: This is a very fun idea, great work organisers!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### **List of [SFF questions posted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bthe-elder-scrolls%5D+created%3A2021-08+is%3Aq) as part of this topic challenge**

- [What is CHIM, and how does it relate to the ludonarrative aspects of the Elder Scrolls games?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/252871/31394) by [nick012000](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/93785/nick012000), 21/08/2021.
- *add entries in the form `https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/<question-ID> by [username](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/<user-ID>), dd/08/2021.`*

---

### **List of [Arqade questions posted](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bthe-elder-scrolls-*%5D+created%3A2021-08+is%3Aq) as part of this topic challenge**

- [How long do I have to wait before bandits take over Helgen Keep?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/389618) by [Tyll'a](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/139342/tylla), 09/08/2021.
- [Why does Lydia keep saying "Looks like you've already got someone with you"?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/390010) by [prince](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/278641/prince), 22/08/2021.
- ...
- *add entries in the form `[title](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/<question-ID>) by [username](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/<user-ID>), dd/08/2021.`*

---

The **highest-voted** of these is *[question URL]*, with a score of *TBD* at the end of August.

The **most viewed** is *[question URL]*, with approximately *TBD* views during August.